# Check page permission by session?

Tags: php, html, security, session

I included `header.php` to every page for header logo and check page permission by `SESSION`!

- So if you request **main.php** without login (session null state), It will display login page and do exit in `header.php` for not showing current page content.
- Its *header.php* is work for every page except `login.php`.Because login page is not show login form

So I want to show login form ,how can I check in `header.php` for its ? Sorry for my poor english :(

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
if($_POST){
 //set session logged in
}
?>
<div class="login-box ">
            <h3> Log In </h3>
            <form method="POST">
                <input type="text" name="user"  placeholder="Type User Name"><br>
                <input type="password" name="pass"  placeholder="Type Password"><br>
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button">
            </form>
            <span id="signup_text">You are not still a member.Click <a href="signup.php">Sign Up</a></span>
</div>
```

---

**header.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<div id="header" class="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <h1>Online Quiz Management</h1>
        </div> 
</div>
<?php        
 if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
            echo "<div id='menu'><ul><li><a href=\"sublist.php\">HOme</a></li><li><a href=\"signout.php\">Signout</a></li></ul></div>";
           }
        else {
             echo "<div class=head1> Your are not logged in<br> Please <a href=login.php>Login</a><div>";
             exit;
        }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>                  
?>
```

---

**main.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
include("header.php");
?>
//show main code  if logged in
```

Comment: A better solution might be to redirect the user to the login page (e.g. `login.php`) when he is not logged in. Then you would create, show and check the form in `login.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a check if the current page is login.php and don't run your block if it is

```
  else if(!basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "login.php") {

             echo "<div class=head1> Your are not logged in<br> Please <a href=login.php>Login</a><div>";
             exit;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u dont need to include the header.php to login.php, since it is check for the session, while the login.php is the session starter...

after all, try to add this to the header.php :

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login'])){
echo  '<script language="javascript">';
echo  'alert("Please Login")';
echo  '</script>';
echo("<script>location.href = 'login.php';</script>");//direct the user to login.php if they aren't logged in
}
```